# Assign all capturing groups of one regex to a hash

Tags: regex, perl, hash

Let's say you have a string that you know will match a regex at least once. That regex has two capturing groups and you want to assign each couple to a key-value pair in a hash.

I was thinking something like this, but I'm not sure if this is the *Perl way* to go - or if it would even work.

```
$string = 'f=banana&c=3;f=strawberry&c=1;f=coconut&c=6';
my %countedfruit;
($countedfruit{$1} = $2) = $string =~ /f=([a-z]+)&c=([0-9]+)/g;

for my $fruit (keys %countedfruit) {
    print "The count of '$fruit' is $countedfruit{$fruit}\n";
}
```

Expected result:

```
The count of 'banana' is 3
The count of strawberry is 1
The count of coconut is 6
```

Actual result:

```
The count of 'coconut' is
```

Comment: Re: "I'm not sure if this [...] would even work": But surely you tried it before posting?

Comment: @Bram wow, you're on a real Perl spree. I wonder if the question limit is in effect for high rep users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just feed the hash with the list of pairs (matches)

```
%countedfruit = $string =~ /f=([a-z]+)&c=([0-9]+)/g;
```

This will issue a warning if there isn't an even-numbered list (with warnings enabled), otherwise key-value pairs in the hash are formed of pairs of consecutive matches in the list returned by `m/`.

Comment: Re: "if pairing doesn't work out right there'll be a nasty bug": Could you elaborate on this? I don't see how `/f=([a-z]+)&c=([0-9]+)/g` could ever *not* generate results in pairs. (Maybe give an example of input that triggers the bug, and the resulting output?)

Comment: @ruakh I dropped the statement about a "nasty bug," in the process correcting a faulty statement. I do know what itches me but can't come up with code to articulate that.  Thank you.